# a const member function, returning a pointer to a non const member variable, why would it be good?

Tags: c++

I work in a large collaboration (of mostly non-professional programmers, I being one of them). I regularly see examples of the following

```
void T::DoChanges(I i); // will make changes to internal structure of T (non-const)
V T::GetValue();

class A
{
private:
  T* fMember;
public:
  A(); 
  T* GetMember() const {return fMember;}
}
```

, Where a use-case would be

```
A a;
I i;
a->GetMember()->DoChanges(i);
V v = a->GetMember()->GetValue();
```

This practice violates a tenant drilled into me when i took programming courses, i.e. that const refers not only to the bitwise structure of the class instance, but the internal logical structure. 
Under this philosophy, the member function should take the following forms:

```
T* GetMember() {return fMember;}
const T* GetMember() const {return fMember;}
```

I have heard that some people think that const should only refer to members, speaking strictly using the c++ terminology. How/why would someone argue for this type of practice?

Answer (score 4):

Making the member function gives the indication to the users of this function that it will not modify **any** class members.
The returned member may or maynot be `const` but making the member function const gives the users of the class a clear indication of the behavior of function.

Comment: I would say the clearness of the indication depends very much on a understanding between the author and user on whether const refers only to members strictly under the meaning of c++ terminology, or if it refers to the members of the logical structure of the type A.

Comment: @qonf: The *understanding* has to expressed through the interface and it is done by declaring the member function a *const* member function.

Comment: No, i respectfully disagree. It would have to be communicated some other way, e.g. documentation. Say the Author writes the class A with a function declared const returning a pointer to a non-const member of the logical structure of A. Say an user, Tom, makes use of A by declaring a const instance of A somewhere in his code, because he thinking that const refers to that the the logical structure remains constant. Then at some later point in his code Tom modifies the instance the pointer points to. Now Tom has unknowingly violated his previous assumption, and possibly introduced a bug.

Comment: The only assumption caused by declaring a method const is that the object will not be modified due to the execution of that method. There is no assumption that callers will not modify the contents of that non-const pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It's largely dependent on the design, but for your case, I don't see why you need two prototypes.

The question you need to ask yourself is whether you want people altering your `T` member via the `get`.

If you do, your prototype should look like:

```
T* GetMember() const {return fMember;}
```

If you don't, make the return const:

```
const T* GetMember() const {return fMember;}
```

The function doesn't have to be `const`, but consider it can be without a problem. That being said, would you call the function inside a different non-const member function? Because if you plan on doing so, it won't work since it's not `const`.

Since you only return a pointer to a member and not actually change anything, I would go with making the function `const`. This also acts as a directive to others working on the project that the function doesn't modify anything internally.

The choice on whether the return should be `const` or not is entirely design-dependent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. However I think you must have either misspoke or missed my point entirely. You say: "Since you only return a pointer to a member and not actually change anything, ...". First of all, the pointer points to member of the logical structure of A, not to a member in terms of standard c++ terminology. Allowing the user of A to modify the logical structure of a A instance I would not call "not actually change anything." This was the central issue of my post, and unless i misunderstand your post, you did not touch on that at all. Forgive my frankness.

Comment: @qonf No missed point, I also was talking about a pointer to a member of A. Which you don't change via the call to GetMember(), you just get the pointer... which you can of course change afterwards.

Comment: GetMember does not technically return a member. It returns a copy of a member, which is a pointer to a T, which is not a member, technically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to reply that this is a question of design, and it's your choice whether you are happy with mutable accessor (in which case you go for the first, `const` version), or if you want to forbid constant references to modify the pointee (in which case you go for the second, two-overloads version).

But coming to think of it, I think your question demonstrates that getters and setters are a bad idea in general. You shouldn't just blindly forward class members (in which case you might as well just make them public members). Rather, your class should offer a meaningful interface that abstracts away the implementation. So ideally the fact that there's a raw pointer in your class should never be of concern to the user, and your interface functions take care of making the relevant logical constness guarantees.

If you choose to forgo these OO design principles, then I suppose you're on your own, and you should do whatever suits your overall design best.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. You make a good argument, but using that philosophy has a heavy cost if your object is required to be heavily modifiable.

Comment: Imagine that T in my example has 10 degrees of freedom in term of modifiability, all of which the user of A needs to be able to manipulate. A needs to either have a duplication of T's interface (10 functions, assuming no 3rd party type to facilitate the transfer of information)), or A needs to take and give a copy/reference of. The first option is costly in terms of implementation/maintenance. The second option is computationally costly if T's assignment operator is costly.

Comment: *take and give a copy/reference of T

Comment: @qonf: Arguably, such a class has too much responsibility (the "god class antipattern"). That's just a gut feeling and you may well have a good reason for such a design, so take this pure philosophising that may or may not apply to your situation.

Comment: My collaboration does analysis of data with complex structures. That means handling large number of independent values. Making types that handle large number of values, and making types that handle those types is practically impossible to avoid, or so it seems to me. In addition, copy/assignment of said types becomes very costly.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, the logical structure of the class is irrelevant of what changes you make to what's pointed to. For example, consider a linked list node. The node is constant as long as the next (and possibly previous) pointers are the same- but the node doesn't care if you change the next node. In addition, T itself might just be an immutable object in design anyway and therefore `const T` is a meaningless distinction.

Comment: In the case i consider, the logical structure is dependent on what's pointed to, and T is mutable. If both weren't true, my question would be moot, though i guess that might have been your point.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine, and useful in the same cases that a `T* const` is.

Consider a hash-table being accessed from multiple threads.  The internal structure needs to not change while another thread is accessing the object, but that doesn't mean the hash-table needs to contain only const pointers.  (Locking the individual objects is much more scalable than locking the whole data structure.)